# can I call PEGA rules from an external application or from Informatica?

Tags: pega

I'm currently working on delveoping a new web application. Some of the business rules that I need to utilize are already implemented in a PEGA implementation. Can I simply call these rules from my webapplication using REST/SOAP? If not, then I will need to recode these complex rules in my application, something I don't want to do.

Any help will do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Pega does provide several options for accessing your data, business rules, or cases using a service although the implementation will vary depending on the version of Pega you are using.

There are service rules within Pega that allow you to create REST or SOAP services (also HTTP, JMS, EJB, etc) without having to write any code.  You would define a new service rule, specify the request parameters, the activity to be run upon invocation, and the response values.

The service activity is where you will specify what business rules you want to interact with.

With the most recent versions of Pega (7.1.8+) there are out of the box APIs that may meet your needs without having to build the service.

There is more information and a detailed walkthrough available in the Pega documentation (PDN).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://pdn.pega.com/pega-api-pega-7-platform for more information about the REST APIs that Matt mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on how you actually want to call you PEGA Rules. There are multiple ways of doing it.

If you want your Application to be embedded inside that web application then you can use IAC ( Internet Application Composer) to embed your existing application.

If you want to use just the Rules to process or execute some logic you can use Service rules (SOAP/REST) by either creating one from scratch by creating a Package, Service Method, Activity to process your logic.

I would highly recommend to go over the list of OOTB Service rules provided on PEGA 7 before creating one.

https://pdn.pega.com/sites/pdn.pega.com/files/help_v72/procomhelpmain.htm#pega_api/pega_api_about.htm

[image]

## Rulesware

Answer (score 0):

Yes absolutely, Best part of PEGA is a way to build seamless applications in a very short span of time.

These are famous ways for PEGA app to interact with external app's --

1. Through API's
2. Mashups where we don't need to depend on API's
3. If we want to fetch DB details of external app's then we can fetch through RDB methods